# datetime jquery UI not showing after theme update

Tags: plugins, date-time, jquery-ui

I had jquery datetime picker working when theme team ask me to upgrade it. That totally broken my site, but now I've fixed almost everything.

Last thing I cant figure out is why Jquery UI datetime picker is not showing anymore. I uninstalled and installed plugin and check everything but **plugin does not seem to be the problem** looking at console, I've seen an error not showing before:

> 2016-04-27 19:43:26.781 jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, **unrecognized expression: .site-header a[href*=#]:not([href=#])**

As long as date and time pickers are mandatory, are marked with `*`

```
[date* fecha class:rosa__style date-format:mm/dd/yy min-date:today first-day:1]</p>
```

URL: http://canvador.com/new/en/home/book/

Any ideas how upgrading the theme can be the cause for this issue?

Comment: More likely that this is a result of JQuery version being updated with WordPress core update.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of jQuery do not support the `href=#` selector syntax and require `href="#"`syntax. Something on your site uses an deprecated syntax.

Deactivate plugins/theme until you find which one is it, and contact its author's support.